# How to dynamicly create bean at application start with properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I use multiple databases to store different entities. My entities and repos are splited in different packeges. And for each database I need to create @Configuration to persist data properly and create tables properly.

Here is @Configuration file for one of me databases

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = { "com.domain.shop.users.repositories" },
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
public class UsersDatabaseConfig {

@Autowired
private DatasourceConnectionManager dscm;

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource1")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return dscm.getDataSource("users");
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, 
@Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource1) {

    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource1)
            .packages("com.domain.shop.users.models")
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager 
transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
 }
}
```

It works pretty fine! But I need to create separate class for each database
I'd like to create such beans at application start reading properties .yml file.
And look at annotations on top - how to pass some parameters to annotations?

Other words, I have .yml file with database connections properties. I want to add some property to each database (like, rootdirectory = com.domain.shop.products). After that I want to create dynamic bean with following code:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "productsEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = { "com.domain.shop.products.repositories" },
    transactionManagerRef = "productsTransactionManager"
)
```

and next

```
@Bean(name = "productsDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return dscm.getDataSource("products");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Profile` annotation. And then create properties file for every profile. E.g.

`@Profile("test")
@Profile("dev")
application-test.yml
application-dev.yml`

Comment: This is not only for dev or test envoironment. I need to create beans on start for evry environment

Comment: It was just example. Just create seperate config file for every profile.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ConditionalOnExpression` will load the `@Configuration class if expression validates to true

```
@ConditionalExpression("${my.rest.controller.enabled}")
```

[or use `@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring", name = "example.values")
```

Comment: I'd like to create these configuration classes dynamicly on app start. May be it possible to create some annotation to persist certain entity in certain database? Like, @Entity and then @PersistIn("databaseName")